# C# file (CodeBehind class) disappearing from project in Visual Studio - Xamarin

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, xamarin

After adding a new Forms ContentPage with a CodeBehind class (Forms ContentPage XAML), everything works perfectly at first. As expected, it creates a .xaml file with a drop down leading to a .xaml.cs file. After adding code, I build my project, and the screens look and work as expected.

After quitting and returning to Visual Studio, however, the .xaml.cs file just disappears from the Solution. This completely breaks my project because Visual Studio can no longer read my event handlers within the .xaml.cs file. The strange thing is that when I press 'reveal in finder' I can see that the .xaml.cs file IS there.

Note, that this does not happen to all my files. Randomly some CodeBehind classes will just disappear from the Solution.

Has anyone else had this problem? What is going on?

Comment: use "Report a Problem" in the help menu

Comment: Good idea, thank you. I just reported it

Answer (score 0):

I am using Visual Studio Mac 8.10 Community and this happens to me all the time, too. I make sure to push my projects to my GitHub rep permanently, so I have a backup. Try to use Rider instead of Visual Studio - it has less flaws according to my experience. If you have an Open Source GitHub Repository which your are committing regularly for 3 months, they will grant you a free license.